# Display output of Javascript expression function

Tags: javascript

I did write some code in JS. It's kind of *Function Expressions*. I've tried to figure it out why this output jump around between that 2 lines (A and B) and still can't get it.

**here's my code**

```js
    Array.prototype.myForEach = function(func){
      for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        console.log("--------");
        func("1 "+ this[i]+" 2");  //A line
       
      }
    };
    
    var colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "PURPLE"];
    
    colors.myForEach(function(color){
        console.log("3 "+color+" 4"); //B line
    });
```

**output result:**

```
--------
3 1 red 2 4
-------
3 1 orange 2 4
-------
3 1 yellow 2 4
-------
3 1 green 2 4
-------
3 1 blue 2 4
-------
3 1 PURPLE 2 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just call two nested functions where every function wraps the value with some numbers.

```js
function a(v) {              // function call before callback call
    return '1 ' + v + ' 2';
}

function b(v) {              // callback
    return '3 ' + v + ' 4';
}

console.log(b(a('#')));
```

Comment: For Line A loop 1; If I correct, it means func(“1 red 2”); Where func is an array. Why it can return as a text?

Comment: `func` is a function, not an array. if it is an array you need square brackes as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Ok, I almost get it. Except this; 
When func("1 "+ this[i]+" 2") becomes >> func("1 red 2");
How can func("1 red 2"); becomes a string like >> "1 red 2"
Where the function func() are?   In short why fucn("1 red 2") becomes just a plain text

Comment: you need a function which returns the parameter of the function, like `function func(value) { return value; }`, without changing the value.

Comment: You mean that JS do this for me right, implicitly ?

Comment: i don't understand.

Comment: I mean, in my code it doesn't need to have a function your suggested 
`function func(value) { return value; }`
and it still can return a value. The point is i don't understand why it can return such texts.

Comment: it depends on the purpose, actually i do not understand what you like to get, a replacement for [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or the use of a *decorator* which takes a value and returns something with the given value.

Comment: In fact, I actually  try to clone `Array.forEach` i'm just curious about it. 
By the way, Thanks a lot Scholz :) I just learned js yesterday- a lot of quirks.